# Cypher query in Python binding for Neo4j with arithmetic operations in WHERE clause

Tags: python, where-clause, neo4j, cypher, arithmetic-expressions

I ran into a problem when running the following Cypher query against my neo4j database in python binding v 1.6:

```
START  n0 = node:my_nodes(label='1'), n1 = node:my_nodes(label='1'), 
       n2 = node:my_nodes(label='2'), n3 = node:my_nodes(label='2'), 
       n4 = node:my_nodes(label='2')
MATCH (n0)-[r0]-(n1),(n0)-[r1]-(n4),(n1)-[r2]-(n2),(n2)-[r3]-(n3)
WHERE (r1.year - r0.year = 1) AND (r2.year - r1.year = 0) AND 
      (r3.year - r2.year = 0)
RETURN count(distinct n0), count(distinct n1),
       count(distinct n2), count(distinct n3),
       count(distinct n4)
```

My database has nodes with indexed properties `label` and relationships with an integer property `year`.
When executing this query, I get an error

```
in decorator return fn(*args, **kwargs)
org.neo4j.cypher.CypherExceptionPyRaisable: Unclosed parenthesis
"WHERE (r1.label - r0.label = 1) AND 
(r2.label - r1.label = 0) AND (r3.label - r2.label = 0)"
                                                               ^
```

I have already played around with parentheses in this query with no success.
Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Edit: I thought the problem was with using neo4j-embedded version 1.6, but I upgraded it till version 1.9.dev0 (compiled from github), but I still get the same error.

Edit2: Thanks to ulkas comment, I found out about interactive cypher console and created [there](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=9n3usw) a sample graph and cypher query (but without index part). There is a problem with the query:

```
 Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.helpers.ThisShouldNotHappenError: 
 Developer: Andres claims that: Unexpected traversal state encountered.
```

Edit3: After playing around with the console, I've figured out that it does not allow undirected relationships and diamond shape pattern matching which should be available according to the [documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-match.html). That is what I got working in the console http://console.neo4j.org/?id=oqspkc . This query fails in Python with the same error message (`Unclosed parenthesis`).
Can I still match diamond shape patterns in neo4j? What can be wrong with python binding?

Comment: have you tried the cypher query in the console ? whether it's cypher or python related problem.